# Real zero of a positive real function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I have a real positive function defined over very large positive real domain which has a single zero in that domain. Function is infinitely differentiable. I am looking for an algorithm to find this needle in the haystack, more like single electron in entire universe.

Comment: Any information about derivatives?

Comment: Is the domain closed and bounded?

Comment: It is actally a non negative continues fuction with infinite number of continuos derivates. As peaceful as it gets, with extremly rare zeroes.

Comment: The derivative is then also zero there. If the second derivative is not zero at that point, then the derivative will change sign, so you can use bisection to locate the root. But this will then also yield other points where the derivative is zero but not the function itself.